# Adding an Image on top of another in Python

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I have a Tkinter canvas that contains

```
def __init__(self, image):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)

    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=self.w, height=self.h, cursor="cross")
    self.canvas.focus_set()

    self.i = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
    self.origimg = image
    self.canvas.create_image(self.w/2, self.h/2, image=self.i)
```

Elsewhere, I crop a portion of the image out and then edit it. I'd like to update the canvas to show this edited image replacing or over the part of the original image from which it was cropped (the dimensions are saved).

Answer (score 0):

Found answer:

PIL paste() method